# Как получить доступ к файлу по директории в проге которая будет использоваться на другом ПК

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Итак, у меня есть файл XML. Для его подключение нужна его директория (что логично). А мне нужно что бы я смог получить доступ к файлу без конкретной директории, так как данная прога будет использоваться на разных компах.

UPD: Предполагается что программа работает локально. В интернете пишут про то, что файлы проги должны хранится в определенной "одинаковой у всех" папке (прим. Documents). Подскажите как это можно реализовать (если нет других вариантов).

Comment: Положите файл в ресурсы, не вижу проблемы, либо просто файлом рядом с исполняемым файлом. Здесь вообще не должно быть проблемы. Вариантов куча, выбор правильного зависит от вашей потребности. От типа приложения тоже зависит, но эти все необходимые для выбора правильного решения факты известны только вам. Вопрос предлагаю закрыть как "хочу то, не знаю что".

Comment: Для каких целей используется файл? Меняется ли его содержимое программой/пользователем? По каким причинам не подходит предложение использовать Environment.SpecialFolder?

Answer (score 1):

Залить XML-файл на сервер и в последствии запрашивать у него этот файл для работы Вашей программы.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне это не подходит. Программа должна работать локально. Вопрос сейчас дополню.

Comment: В таком случае единственный возможный на мой взгляд вариант -- "вшить" все требуемые файлы в саму программу (напрмер, как это сделано в .exe-файлах) и так отправлять.

Answer (score 0):

Мои Документы и прочее: [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0). Там же и пример.

Или, если нужна папка, где приложение лежит: [AppContext.BaseDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Вы уверены, что вопрос был про то же что этот ответ?